# Problema al validar DNI JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy empezando a aprender JavaScript y tenía una duda a la hora de validar un DNI.

La expresión regular para comprobar que tenga 8 números y una letra del abecedario no me funciona.

```js
//Se pide el número completo del DNI (12345678X)
var dni = prompt("Introzuca su número de DNI");
  
//Se separan los números de la letra
var letraDNI = dni.substring(8, 9);
var numDNI = parseInt(dni.substring(0, 8));

//Se calcula la letra correspondiente al número
var letras = ['T', 'R', 'W', 'A', 'G', 'M', 'Y', 'F', 'P', 'D', 'X', 'B', 'N', 'J', 'Z', 'S', 'Q', 'V', 'H', 'L', 'C', 'K', 'E', 'T'];
var letraCorrecta = letras[numDNI % 23];


//Se comprueba que el formato es válido 
if(numDNI == /\d{8}[a-z A-Z]/){
  numDNI = parseInt(prompt("Introzuca un número válido de DNI"));
}
//Se comprueba si la letra introducida es igual a la calculada
else{

  if(letraDNI.toUpperCase() != letraCorrecta){
    alert("Has introducido una letra incorrecta" + "\n" + "Tu letra debería ser: " + letraCorrecta);
  }
  else{
    alert("Enhorabuena hemos podido validar tu DNI");
  }
}
```

Comment: He probado tu solución en la consola java de mi Google Chrome (F12 - Console). He declarado mi DNI como: var dni = "Aquí he escrito mi DNI" Y me ha funcionado perfectamente.

Comment: Funciona bien, y mal! Deberias poner una alerta que indique que no has alcanzado el numero digitos. Porque aunque te de error, te calcula la letra con 4 por ejemplo.

Answer (score 5):

Tienes varios problemas con el uso de la expresión regular:

```
//Se comprueba que el formato es válido 
if(numDNI == /\d{8}[a-z A-Z]/){     
    numDNI = parseInt(prompt("Introzuca un número válido de DNI"));
}
```

- Comparar una variable con una expresión regular mediante `==` sólo sirve para decirte si la variable es la misma expresión regular
- Incluso si funcionase, estás diciendo que lo vuelva a pedir si es igual, no cuando NO es igual.
- Incluso si funcionase y hubieses puesto !=, estás comparando un número y no un string (has quitado ya la letra).
- Cuando lo pides de nuevo, te quedas sólo con el número y además no estás haciendo ninguna comprobación de nuevo.

El código debería ser algo como lo siguiente:

```js
let dni='';
while(!(/^\d{8}[a-zA-Z]$/.test(dni))){
  dni = prompt("Introduzca un número de DNI: 8 números y una letra");
}

//Se separan los números de la letra
var letraDNI = dni.substring(8, 9).toUpperCase();
var numDNI = parseInt(dni.substring(0, 8));

//Se calcula la letra correspondiente al número
var letras = ['T', 'R', 'W', 'A', 'G', 'M', 'Y', 'F', 'P', 'D', 'X', 'B', 'N', 'J', 'Z', 'S', 'Q', 'V', 'H', 'L', 'C', 'K', 'E', 'T'];
var letraCorrecta = letras[numDNI % 23];

if(letraDNI!= letraCorrecta){
  alert("Has introducido una letra incorrecta\nTu letra debería ser: " + letraCorrecta);
} else {
  alert("Enhorabuena hemos podido validar tu DNI");

}
```

Comment: ¿Se permite un espacio como último caracter? ¿O en realidad `[a-z A-Z]` debería corregirse por `[a-zA-Z]`?

Comment: @Mariano Tienes razón, sobra el espacio

Answer (score 3):

Antes de todo deberias comprobar que la longitud del dato introducido es correcta:

```
if (dni.length !=9)
```

Para comprobar que el numero es correcto deberias controlar la excepcion en el parseo :

```
try 
{
  var numDNI = parseInt(dni.substring(0, 8));    
} 
catch (NumberFormatException e) 
{

      //Controlamos la excepcion
}
```

Comprobada que la longitud es la correcta entonces si puedes mirar el valor de la letra, sino tendrias un error en la dimension del array:
Comprobamos que es una letra el valor 9 del array:

```
if (Character.isLetter(this.dni.charAt(8) == true)
```

Ya tienes ahi comprobado que el formato es correcto o no al ser solo numeros y **no** deberias volver a comprobar el formato con el codigo:

```
//Se comprueba que el formato es válido 
if(numDNI == /\d{8}[a-z A-Z]/){
    numDNI = parseInt(prompt("Introzuca un número válido de DNI"));
}
```

Haciendo todas esas comprobaciones y cambios, quedaria así tu codigo:

```
//Se pide el número completo del DNI (12345678X)
var dni = prompt("Introzuca su número de DNI");

//Se comprueba que la dimension del valor introducido es correcto
if (dni.length == 9)
{
    //Se separan los números de la letra
    try 
    {
        var numDNI = parseInt(dni.substring(0, 8)); 
    } 
    catch (NumberFormatException e) 
    {
        //Controlamos la excepcion , el parseo falla. Algun valor no es numero
    }
    //Se calcula la letra correspondiente al número
    var letras = ['T', 'R', 'W', 'A', 'G', 'M', 'Y', 'F', 'P', 'D', 'X', 'B', 'N', 'J', 'Z', 'S', 'Q', 'V', 'H', 'L', 'C', 'K', 'E', 'T'];
    var letraCorrecta = letras[numDNI % 23];
    //Se comprueba que el ultimo valor es una letra
    if (Character.isLetter(this.dni.charAt(8) == true)
    {
        //Comprobamos que la letra es la calculada
        if(letraDNI.toUpperCase() != letraCorrecta)
        {
            alert("Has introducido una letra incorrecta" + "\n" + "Tu letra debería ser: " + letraCorrecta);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Enhorabuena hemos podido validar tu DNI");
        }   
    }
    else
    {
    //Error. El valor final no es una letra
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Probaste que el código funcione? Lo primero que veo es `lenght` que está mal escrito, que debería ser `length`.

Comment: No he podido probarlo. Gracias por la nota, modifico el error.

Answer (score 1):

**Sin regex**

Te he metido un par de funciones. Que comprueban tanto la letra como te la calculan y en caso de que haya fallos te van avisando.

Echale un vistazo, puede que te sea util.

```js
function comprobardni(dni){
  var numDNI = dni.substring(0, 8);

  if(numDNI.length!=8){
    return comprobardni(prompt("Has Introducido mal el dni:"));
  }else{
    var letra = comprobardni_letra(dni);
    var letracorrecta = calcular_letra(numDNI);
    if(letra===letracorrecta){
      return alert("Enhorabuena hemos podido validar tu DNI");
    }else{
      return comprobardni(prompt("Has introducido una letra incorrecta" + "\n" + "Tu letra debería ser: " + letracorrecta));
    }    
  }
}

function comprobardni_letra(dni){
  var letraDNI = dni.substring(8, 9);
  
  return letraDNI;
}

function calcular_letra(dni){
  var cadena="TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET";
  var posicion = dni % 23;
  return cadena.substring(posicion,posicion+1);
}

var dni = comprobardni_numero(prompt("Introzuca su número de DNI"));
```